# JPQL, search if value is IN or NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

I have a problem using JPQL.

Here is my query :

```sql
SELECT [columns] FROM Table t 
WHERE [conditions] AND t.aColumn.aSubColumn IN ([values]) 
OR t.aColumn IS NULL
```

So to explain it, t contains a column that is a foreign key to another table (so an object). I am trying to see if a field of that table contains some values, but if the foreign key is null, then we don't take it into consideration in the query. How can I achieve that ?

**PS :** When I try to run the query, the results are null because the FK is null, so it doesn't find anything in the IN clause.

**EDIT : original query**

```java
@NamedQuery(name = "Commande.findCustom", query = "SELECT c FROM Commande c WHERE "
            + "(c.idChargement LIKE :idChargement OR c.idChargement IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.codeTransporteur LIKE :codeTransporteur OR c.codeTransporteur IS NULL) AND "
            + "(((c.dateChargementPrevu BETWEEN :dateDebut AND :dateFin) OR "
            + "c.dateChargementPrevu IS NULL) OR "
            + "((c.dateLivraisonPrevue BETWEEN :dateDebut AND :dateFin) OR "
            + "c.dateLivraisonPrevue IS NULL)) AND "
            + "(c.idDernierStatut.idListeStatutsCommande IN "
            + "(SELECT l.idListeStatutsCommande FROM Listestatutscommande l "
            + "WHERE l.idStatut IN :idStatut) OR c.idDernierStatut IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.raisonSocialeDestinataire LIKE :raisonSociale OR c.raisonSocialeDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.adresseDestinataire LIKE :adresseDestinataire OR c.adresseDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.codeDestinataire LIKE :codeDestinataire OR c.codeDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.codePostalDestinataire LIKE :codePostal OR c.codePostalDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.villeDestinataire LIKE :villeDestinataire OR c.villeDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.paysDestinataire LIKE :codePays OR c.paysDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "c.idPartenaire IN :idPartenaire "
            + "ORDER BY c.dateLivraisonPrevue DESC")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `t.aColumn` then inner join is used in the background. Try this

```
SELECT [columns] FROM Table t left join t.aColumn ac
WHERE [conditions] AND ac.aSubColumn IN ([values])
```

**UPDATE** after adding real query used

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Commande.findCustom", query = "SELECT c FROM Commande c left join c.idDernierStatut idds WHERE "
            + "(c.idChargement LIKE :idChargement OR c.idChargement IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.codeTransporteur LIKE :codeTransporteur OR c.codeTransporteur IS NULL) AND "
            + "(((c.dateChargementPrevu BETWEEN :dateDebut AND :dateFin) OR "
            + "c.dateChargementPrevu IS NULL) OR "
            + "((c.dateLivraisonPrevue BETWEEN :dateDebut AND :dateFin) OR "
            + "c.dateLivraisonPrevue IS NULL)) AND "
            + "(idds is null or idds.idListeStatutsCommande IN "
            + "(SELECT l.idListeStatutsCommande FROM Listestatutscommande l "
            + "WHERE l.idStatut IN :idStatut)) AND "
            + "(c.raisonSocialeDestinataire LIKE :raisonSociale OR c.raisonSocialeDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.adresseDestinataire LIKE :adresseDestinataire OR c.adresseDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.codeDestinataire LIKE :codeDestinataire OR c.codeDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.codePostalDestinataire LIKE :codePostal OR c.codePostalDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.villeDestinataire LIKE :villeDestinataire OR c.villeDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "(c.paysDestinataire LIKE :codePays OR c.paysDestinataire IS NULL) AND "
            + "c.idPartenaire IN :idPartenaire "
            + "ORDER BY c.dateLivraisonPrevue DESC")
```

Comment: Can you post the real query that you are testing? Because if you have `t.aColumn` in the select clause, that will also force inner join to be used. Additionally, you can print out generated SQL to see what exactly is happening.

Comment: This is what I did in the first place (before editing), it doesn't work. I have found a workaround, I put an AFTER INSERT trigger in the DB to put at least one line, meaining that he will have a line and find something with the IN clause

Comment: I've edited my suggestion, added `idds is null or `. If this doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: It doesn't work too. But it doesn't change from my original query, does it ?

Comment: It is different because it uses left join for `c.idDernierStatut` and latter its alias `idds`. Also `idds is null` check is first in `or` expression which means that `IN` condition shouldn't be evaluated at all when `idds` is null.